# How to auto update json data without rebuilding the table

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a jQuery Ajax request from POSTGRESQL database. I am able to render or parse the data in an HTML element format like tables but would like to know how can I auto-update the data of the code below without rebuilding the table all the time? Any help?

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$.ajax({
    url:'data.php',
    type:'GET',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (key, value){
            $.each(value, function(k, v){ 
                if(k === "initial_line"){
                    $("#demoTable >tbody:last").append(
                        $('<tr>').append(
                            $('<td>').append(v)
                            .append(
                                $('</td>').append(
                                    $('</tr>')
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        );
                }
                if(k === "pass"){
                    $("#demoTable >tbody >tr:last").append(
                        $('<td>').append(v)
                        .append(
                            $('</td>')
                            )
                        );
                }
                if(k === "fail"){
                    $("#demoTable >tbody >tr:last").append(

                        $('<td>').append(v)
                        .append(
                            $('</td>')
                            )
        );
                }
            });
        });
    }
 })      
});
```

Comment: Well, this code would render the table (**when removing the syntax errors** *check your console for more details*). An update would occur when you send a request with the new data. Javascript events + `$.ajax`.

Comment: I'd suggest using a view rendering library such as react

Comment: Can anybody help with an example? (code)